# How do I connect the geth console to an INFURA endpoint?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura

Rather than have a local node on my PC, I'd like to be able to attach the geth cli console to INFURA and then issue requests within geth's java console, e.g. `web3.eth.getBalance(<address>)`

I signed up for INFURA and received an email with some endpoints to use, but I am unclear what specific commands I should use so that my geth console attaches to one of those endpoints.

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/@LibertyLocked/using-light-geth-node-with-metamask-714f537bd696 One of the simple way to solve issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you can't connect to a remote host because `geth attach` works via ipc.

Try this instead:

```
> npm install web3
> node 
> Web3 = require("web3");
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<your access key>:8545"));
> web3.eth.blockNumber
```

**Update**

Since version 1.4 `geth attach` supports rpc also however it doesn't work for me:

```
> geth attach https://mainnet.infura.io/<my access key>:8545
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: EOF
```

Comment: @mesqueeb check my answer below

Comment: `web3.eth.blockNumber` does not work, but you can do it asynchronously: `web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(res => console.log(res))`

Answer (score 2):

The main infura nodes do not support `geth attach`. Infura maintains legacy nodes that they use for testing that it works for .

`geth attach https://gmainnet.infura.io`(geth)
or
`geth attach https://pmainnet.infura.io` (parity)

Comment: I get this error
`Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: invalid character 'h' in literal true (expecting 'r')`

Comment: I get this error: `Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post https://gmainnet.infura.io: context deadline exceeded`