# How to use 'geth attach' with Infura?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, infura, rpc

I have a project in Infura and the project ID is `6f...3a`. I'm having problem to start `geth attach` process with Infura.

[image]

I tried all protocols (`http`, `https`, `ws` and `wss`) but all failed.
Did I miss something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I connect the geth console to an INFURA endpoint?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39936/how-do-i-connect-the-geth-console-to-an-infura-endpoint)

Comment: I tried them all but didn't work.